# Integer value from decimal number

Tags: integer, decimal

Need to convert an 8 digit number in the form of

(d7 d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 d1 d0)
where di : i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 is the multiplier for 10i : i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Im confused as to how to convert it using this format

(d7 d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 + 100) = Integer Value.

number being a 8 digit = 10192517

I'm not sure if i need to multiply all the numbers individually by their power of 10? so 10^1 + 10^0 etc etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated and accepted. I simply need to understand it, an answer is not necessary.

EDIT: For context purposes it is asking me to compute an integer value (uID) for the 8 digit student number. Once i have done that i then have to convert into a 32bit complement sequence, sorry for the confusion....

Comment: What do you want 10192517 to be converted into? Why don't you give a complete example of what you want?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't very clear, I'm trying to understand how to convert 10192517(decimal) into an integer using "(d7 d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 + 100) = Integer Value."

Sorry if i'm confusing you

Comment: You haven't answered my question at all. If 10192517 is the input, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: Your student identification number is an 8-digit number.
For instance, d7 d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 d1 d0 where di : i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 is the multiplier for 10i : i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.
1. Compute the integer value uID = (d7 d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 + 100).

Comment: What are you saying? that you have an array of individual digits that you want to convert to an integer? Perhaps you can give a better example of what is needed or edit the question to make it clearer ??? Also if this is homework, please add the homework tag

Comment: don't know if that adds any context? I'm not sure what the question is asking for either. The enxt step after this is a 32 bit compliment sequence.

Comment: @LewisFletch Will you answer my question? If 10192517 is the input, what do you want the output to be after conversion? Give us the output number, not a formula with a non-standard notation that can be interpreted in multiple ways leading to confusion and waste of time.

Comment: @SusamPal The think is i don't actually know...all it says is " an integer value" from the 8 digit decimal input. It's very unclear hence why i am trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what you want to ask. I have made several requests for clarification in the comments, but you won't answer what I ask. Instead, you keep repeating the same formula which isn't very clear. From whatever I could understand this may be the solution to your problem?

```
>>> n = 10192517
>>> n/100 + 100
102025
```

i.e. 101925 + 100 = 102025.

Comment: Could possibly be correct, i have scoured the net for explanations and my lecture slides as well...it's very unclear.

Sorry for wasting your time. I could only provide you with what i had which was that one formula.